# Silverlight - Group XAML into "controls"?

Tags: silverlight, .net-4.0

New Silverlight developer here (well sorta).  I was wondering what the standard is to group xaml.  Basically, I have a list that is used in several places and I want to be able to use it without having to manage it in 10 different spots.

Whats the best way to do this (in ASP and WinForms, I'd create a custom control, but for XAML i just want it to basically inject the xaml, no functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends upon your definition of *"manage it"* and *"no functionality"*. You either create your own user control (which doesn't have to do much), or use a prepackaged one.

Answer (score 3):

From Scott Guthrie himself: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-6-using-user-controls-to-implement-master-detail-scenarios.aspx

What you're looking to do is create a User Control and then you can add it to a page like any other control. Follow the steps (or, at least, similar steps) to create your own User Control.